# Sentinel::authenticate() doesn't work

Tags: laravel-5, php-7, cartalyst-sentinel

I'm using Laravel 5.2, with a fresh Sentinel 2.0 installation, registering works fine, but attempting to login returns the user, but does not set any cookie or session or whatsoever..

## **update1**

At this moment I've found that no cookie/session is saved whatsoever. I can't really figure out as to why the cookie is not pushed.

**AuthController.php**

```
namespace App\Modules\Auth\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller {

    public function getLogin() {
        return view("Auth::login");
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request) {

        $credentials = [
            'email'    => $request->input('login_email'),
            'password' => $request->input('login_password'),
        ];


        if (\Sentinel::authenticate($credentials)) {
            return redirect('core/dashboard');
        }
    }

}
```

**`\Sentinel::check();` var_dump() before redirect**

```
object(Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser)#188 (27) {
  ["table":protected]=>
  string(5) "users"
  ["fillable":protected]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "email"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "password"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "last_name"
    [3]=>
    string(10) "first_name"
    [4]=>
    string(11) "permissions"
  }
  ["persistableKey":protected]=>
  string(7) "user_id"
  ["persistableRelationship":protected]=>
  string(12) "persistences"
  ["loginNames":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "email"
  }
  ["connection":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["primaryKey":protected]=>
  string(2) "id"
  ["perPage":protected]=>
  int(15)
  ["incrementing"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["timestamps"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["attributes":protected]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["email"]=>
    string(25) "test@dev.local"
    ["password"]=>
    string(60) "$2y$10$wXHwd6ubbHWWXU9CBI/7AOdDsHY.f7t8b1Kjem0m1ep7Ud.9M/4i6"
    ["permissions"]=>
    NULL
    ["last_login"]=>
    object(Carbon\Carbon)#192 (3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2016-01-06 15:15:42.000000"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(3) "UTC"
    }
```

Any ideas what can go wrong?

in `.env` the session driver is set to `database`, and the sessions table stays empty after login. No cookie is set either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue. I had to create a route group with the web middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    Route::get('modules', ['uses' => 'ModuleController@index', 'as' => 'modules']);
    Route::get('modules/{name}', ['uses' => 'ModuleController@show', 'as' => 'modules.show']);
    Route::post('modules/{module}/publish', ['as' => 'module.publish', 'uses' => 'ModuleController@publish']);
    Route::post('modules/{module}/enable', ['as' => 'module.enable', 'uses' => 'ModuleController@enable']);
    Route::post('modules/{module}/disable', ['as' => 'module.disable', 'uses' => 'ModuleController@disable']);
});
```

Worked as expected then.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer in another answer here on stackoverflow. Need to enable 'web' middleware.. sigh

Wish they'd documented that somewhere..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34529550/775260

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Sentinel uses Cookies/Sessions. If you want to use another middleware group than web make sure that it middleware for those are added to the group.