# Laravel 5.2 nested route groups with middleware

Tags: php, laravel-5

Problems:

1. Session::flash won't  work
2. Weird route parameters

**Problem 1**

I'm experiencing a bug where Session::flash won't  work.
I also found a workaround but it's.. weird.

I think there's something wrong with nested groups and middlewares.

Code:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::group([
            'prefix' => '{locale}',
            'middleware' => ['localized']
        ], function($locale)
    {
        Route::resource('/', 'ProductController', ['only' => ['index']]);
        Route::get('/cart', 'CartController@show')->name('show-shopping-cart');
    });

    Route::patch('/cart', 'CartController@update')->name('patch-cart');
});
```

now..
this will work if I modify kernel.php this way:

from

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

to

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
];

protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

what do you think about it?

**Problem 2**

In the routes above, ProductController@show is getting 2 parameters: locale and id.

For example if I navigate to /en/4

```
function show($id){
    dd($id);
}
```

$id = "en"

it would work this way:

```
function show($locale, $id){
    dd($id);
}
```

is this by design?
If so is there a way to avoid the $locale being passed to routes inside the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36298013/4805056

the original post says to replace

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
   ...
});
```

with

```
Route::group(['middlewareGroups' => ['web']], function () {
   ...
});
```